# Characterization of measurable G such that $G \circ Z$ has a density with respect to Lebesgue Measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, radon-nikodym

Assume Z is a real valued random variable such that it's distribution has a density with respect to Lebesgue Measure (i.e. its Radon-Nikodym derivative w.r.t Lebesgue measure exists.) Then what is the characterization of measurable real valued functions G, such that the distribution of $G \circ Z$ has a density with respect to Lebesgue measure as well?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.